# how to store & retrieve multiple users data i.e name,email and password in swift 3 using singleton class,arrays

Tags: swift3

I have designed signUp & logIn page, after registration I need to store all the user data (i.e., name, email,password ) in class array using singleton class and check when the user going to login.

```
class UserDetails{

    var name  : String
    var email : String
    var mobile: String
    var password : String
    var confirmPassword : String
    init(name:String, email:String, mobile:String, password:String, confirmPassword: String) {

        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.password = password
        self.confirmPassword = confirmPassword

        }
    init(){

        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.mobile = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.confirmPassword = ""

       }

    }
    class Data: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Data()

    var stored : userData!

    func Get(data : userData)
    {
        stored = data

    }



var  details = [UserDetails]()
    let dataStore = UserDetails(name: name!, email: email!, mobile: mobileNumber!, password: password!, confirmPassword: confirmPassword!)

        details.append(dataStore)
        Data.sharedInstance.Get(data: details)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  extension UIViewController{


      class user {


    var user_name : String
    var user_Email : String
    var user_password : String
    var item_Mobile : String

    init(user_name : String, user_Email : String, user_password : String, item_Mobile : String) {


        self.user_name = user_name
        self.user_Email = user_Email
        self.user_password = user_password

        self.item_Mobile = item_Mobile




    }


}
```

In ViewController

```
           var userData = [user]()
```

if to want to access globally

```
          static  var userData = [user]()
```

To Add values use

//For local

```
        userData.append(cartItem(user_name: "Demo1",
                                                    user_Email: "demo@demo.com",
                                                    user_password: "hhhhhhh",
                                                    item_Mobile: "9889878888"))
```

//For Using global

```
       viewControllername.userData.append(cartItem(user_name: "Demo1",
                                                    user_Email: "demo@demo.com",
                                                    user_password: "hhhhhhh",
                                                    item_Mobile: "9889878888"))
```

to access data

```
           userData[i]. user_name
```

But i suggest you to use userdefaults in place of this